# PowerShell property Count cannot be found on this object

Tags: arrays, powershell, tivoli

I am trying to count some lines output by a command. Basically all the lines which end in " Y " in this example.

Fist Capture the command results:

```
PS> $ItsAgents = tacmd listSystems -n Primary:SomeHost:NT
PS> $ItsAgents
Managed System Name      Product Code Version     Status
Primary:SomeHost:NT NT           06.30.07.00 Y
SomeHost:Q7         Q7           06.30.01.00 N
```

Now count the online ones:

```
PS> $AgentCount = ($ItsAgents | Select-String ' Y ').Count
PS> $AgentCount 
1
```

Now that all works as I expect. So I put it in my script like this:

```
$ItsAgents = tacmd listSystems -n $agent
Write-Host $ItsAgents
$BeforeCount = ($ItsAgents | Select-String ' Y ').Count
```

And when the script runs (under `Set-StrictMode`) I get:

```
The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exists.
At Y:\Scripts\newMoveAgents.ps1:303 char:7
+             $BeforeCount = ($ItsAgents | Select-String ' Y ').Count
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

The `Write-Host` does output sane results so `$agent` is set correctly and the `tacmd` command is running OK
So why does it fail in the script, but work on command line?

Comment: OK I have found it does work in some cases, but not in others, the output of `$ItsAgents` shows it is working when more than two lines of results come back it looks to work fine, but this one errors:
    `Managed System Name      Product Code Version     Status 
    Primary:S1TWANAT01STD:NT NT           06.30.07.00 Y` With the same `The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists....`

Comment: The example with only two lines returned works fine on the command line though, odd.

Comment: Presumably the `$ItsAgents` is a single string, try to split it into separate lines: `$ItsAgents = (tacmd listSystems -n Primary:SomeHost:NT)  -Split '[\r\n]'`

Comment: Thanks @iRon. I tried your suggestion: I have updated my code to `$ItsAgents = ( tacmd listSystems -n $agent ) -Split '[\r\n]'` But I still get the same error in script (and no error on command line)

Comment: Rectification: To avoid empty lines, the split command should be: `-Split '[\r\n]+'` (but I do not expect this to resolve the error)

Comment: Anyways, I am not able to reproduce the error, even with a null (`$Null`), array including null (`@(Null)`), or any strange object like: `($Null | Select-String ' Y ').Count`. In other words, try to find out the object type that causes the error. (is `$ItsAgents` still a string array as presumed? check e.g.: `$ItsAgents.PSTypeNames`). A quick solution might be to force the result to an array by adding an `@` sign: `@($ItsAgents | Select-String ' Y ').Count`.

Comment: Which version are you using? What's the output from `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: `$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1012
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1012
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `@()` operator to force the output to always be an array:

```
$BeforeCount = @($ItsAgents | Select-String ' Y ').Count
```

> The array sub-expression operator creates an array, even if it
> contains zero or one object.
> ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6#the-array-sub-expression-operator))

*Note: Afaik it should work the same way both as a script and inside the console. Maybe your commands produce different output, where the console version returns 2+ results but for some reason the script version only 1 or 0 results, which would be the reason why there is no `Count` property.*

Comment: Thanks @marsze that has solved my problem. It is indeed possible that some instances would return a count of zero when running in the script.